# How do I exit a function in the terminal on mac and how can I print something in terminal?

Tags: python, speech-to-text

When I type in the following, I want to be able to exit the ... and receive a new prompt, however when i click enter it keeps me within the function. How can I exit without creating the error.

```
>>> harvard = sr.AudioFile('harvard.wav')
>>> with harvard as source:
...     audio = r.record(source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing the 'Enter' key twice.

Comment: For clarity, pressing enter the first time will give you another continuation prompt `...`, don't worry about typing on this line and just hit enter again and it'll evaluate the "function" (in this case, a context manager).